# Can I get drops from the Overpass, Cobblestone, or Baggage Collection through regular gameplay?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm a little confused.   I haven't received any mission drops yet, yet I have yet to see anyone receive any of the items from that collection through normal gameplay.

Is the only way to get items from those 3 collections through doing missions, or can I get one of them through regular gameplay (i.e., casual, comp, etc.)

Comment: Oops.. Sorry - I'll delete my answer and try again.. It's quite hard to read on a mobile phone especially with a very small screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Right, woops - Sorry; didn't see your whole question thanks to a very small screen... Now that I'm on a PC, here goes:

---

Firstly, to be eligible for mission drops, you would have to have bought the Operation Breakout pass (which is avaliable in-game or from the market).
Now, to get the mission drops, you just have to play games. They don't count to your total drop limit, but you get 2-3 missions every week.
When you get a mission, you'll have to do a specific killing task (or winning competitive maps). When you have completed the mission, you'll get the drop at the end of the game in  which you completed it in.
*(Note: Mission  progress will only be recorded if you finish the game, and not leave half-way)*

**Answering your question:**
To get the gun drops from the three collections, you must complete missions... And, to get missions... Well, they drop just like crates and guns.

## You CANNOT get them through regular drops . Only as mission rewards, which can be recieved through regular drops.

Also, as for you not recieving any drops - Could it be that you have already hit the "2 missions + 2 crates + 2 guns" (or something along those lines) drop limit for this week? Or not stay until the end of matches (series of rounds)?

Comment: This didn't answer my question. I'm asking if those specific collections can only be found through regular official server gameplay or only through completing missions, not how to get drops.

Comment: I answered your question now. Please check at the revised answer... (I couldn't see half of it because I was on a mobile phone)

Comment: I'll answer this honestly. Before I purchased the breakout pass today, I had no mission drops, despite playing nearly 6 hours, crappy weapon skins from other collections (not from the 3 newest ones), and a few Phoenix cases here and there. The moment after I purchased the pass and went to a game, I got two missions and completed them to get the items.

Comment: Then it probably that you have reached this week's drop limit cap. All you can do is wait for the next week which resets either on a Tuesday or Thursday. (TBH, nobody actually knows when it resets) -- If you reach the limit, non-drop counting items (like the missions) do not drop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by specific collection but I'm trying to guess you mean the different "event" like Missions CS:Go introduces now and then.

At the Moment there are Missions you can do like: „Win Competitive on de_Inferno“ if you achieve that you get 1 Item form the new Collection.
You can only have 2 Missions at a Time and Missions can be received through random drops.
And you need to buy the "entry ticket" like Token to access thouse Missions.

As far as Drops go Theoretical you can get any random Drop from any Collection.

The Drop system is a very Mysterious thing and is very strong discussed in many Forums.

Comment: Drops only contain items that are crates, event-specific items (like the missions) and weapons from the following collections: Train, Arms Deal and a few more, most of which are quite old. As for the new collections, they're not in the drop system. You only get them for doing rewards... Neither do crate collections appear in the drop system..

Comment: EDIT: The Arms Deal collection might be a crate series. I'll get the names of the collections that drop when I get onto a PC.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible my friend got a m4a1-s masterpiece mw from the overpass collection dropped during a normal game